# Laravel consider only the required columns from the request and ignore any other key values if present

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In the Laravel API, I am passing the request input json with few additional key:values which I require in other part of the business logic of the API function. When I pass the array `$request->all()`, of the formal parameter `Request $request` of the Controller function to the Model function and directly pass it to the Eloquent `create()` function as follows:

```
StatusModel::create($request);
```

I get the error,

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'app' in 'field
>   list' (SQL: update `tbl_points` set `team_id` = 4, `tour_id` = 10,
>   `match_id` = 254, `win` = 0, `loss` = 1, `tie` = 1, `n_r` = 1, `pt` =
>   1, `nrr` = 1, `app` = 3 where (`team_id` = 4 and `tour_id` = 10 and
>   `match_id` = 254)).

I want to pass the input request array as it is and want the laravel to ignore the columns name keys from the array which are not present in the database.
EG: Following is my input json, in which "app":3 is an extra key value not present in table.

```
{
"team_id": 4,
"tour_id": 10,
"match_id": 254,
"win": 0,
"loss": 1,
"tie": 1,
"n_r": 1,
"pt": 1,
"nrr": 1,
"app": 3
}
```

My Model Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\BaseModels;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TablePoints extends Model
{   
    protected $table = 'tbl_points';    
    protected $fillable = ['team_id','tour_id','match_id','win','loss','tie','n_r','pt','nrr'];    
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

On dd($request->all()) I get the following in output:

```
array:10 [
  "team_id" => 4
  "tour_id" => 10
  "match_id" => 254
  "win" => 0
  "loss" => 1
  "tie" => 1
  "n_r" => 1
  "pt" => 1
  "nrr" => 1
  "app" => 3
]
```

How to avoid getting such errors by making code ignore extra key value pairs.

Note: I don't want to create a new array and copy values of required keys from request array and use it. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use `except` function. Try this:

```
StatusModel::create($request->except('app'));
```

This will return all fields except for `app` field.

You can also use it with an array to ignore multiple fields. Ex:

```
$request->except(['field1', 'field2']);
```

If you need to exclude all irrelevant data, you can use a code hack like this:

In StatusModel:

```
public function getFillable()
{
    return $this->fillable;
}
```

And then in Controller, use `only` method to filter the attributes in request:

```
$statusModel = new StatusModel();
$fields = $request->only($statusModel->getFillable());
$statusModel->fill($fields);
$statusModel->save();
```

Comment: Ok. But what in the scenario when user of the api passess some unknown key:values by mistake or for some hack

Comment: I edited the answer with this situation. Please, take a look.

Comment: This was awesome, can this solution can be modified to use with create() method. Like, StatusModel::create($fields);

Comment: The problem is that `$fillable` is not static in Model. So, you can't get it without an object. To use create, which is a static method, it would be better if you could call `StatusModel::getFillable()`. But this is not possible, since you can't retrieve a object variable statically.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a protected `fillable` field in your model, which will contain all the field that you want to insert data into.

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Comment: I am doing that still, I am not getting the expected bahaviour

Comment: I have edited the question to show my Model code and added the output of dd($request->all()) in question.